# How not to map an object through the entire response

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, mapping

I currently have a table that has 3 different entries showing from axios call. I'm mapping through that response with a `const details` object to test data in my response. I am successfully able to map my `const details` object  for all 3 responses. But I would like to only have my details object display for 
2/3 entries of the table, not the full 3. What is the best way to not have my object map to the final entry?

```
const details = 
        {
            ActionStatus: "Pending",
            RequestedBy: "Jon Snow",
            ActionRequested: "Canceled"
        },

    const getInfo= () => {
        return infoApi
            .getDirectInfo({
                date: selectedDate,
            })
            .then(response => {
                console.log(response)
                dispatch({
                    type: "FETCH_INFO",
                    payload: {
                        loading: false,
                        data: response.map(r=>({...r,...details})),
                        lastUpdated: new Date().getTime()
                    }
                })}
            )
```

Comment: `Array.map()` will always result in a new array of the same length as the input array (it maps it one-to-one). If you want to reduce the size of an array based on some criteria, you can use `Array.filter()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Array.map()` will always result in a new array of the same length as the input array (it maps it one-to-one). If you want to reduce the size of an array based on some criteria, you can use `Array.filter()`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter